# Using a client certificate to crawl an https site

Tags: search

SO, I create a crawl rule for an https:// site. under where to specify the type of account to crawl, I choose the "client certificate". I performed a full crawl on the web app, and I get " could not find / access the specified client certificate. The default content access account has full read permission to the web app, the client certificate is imported to the local computer personal and trusted root store. But I can't get crawl to work with the client cert. Please help, what I'm I missing?. thanks.

Comment: Does the specified account have rights to the Private Key?